# fx:id and initialize() not running in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to create a user interface, starting with a grid. I built the grid in scenebuilder and I now want to use my controller to add columns and rows. However, my program does not seem to run the initialise() in my controller as the grid does not change size.
This is my main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;    import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    //@Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            int width = 7;
            int height = 7;         
            final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new GUIController(width, height));
            final Parent root = 
            FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));    
            final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setTitle("GUI");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my controller class:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class GUIController {

    private int width;
    private int height;

    public GUIController(int givenWidth, int givenHeight) {//runs this
        width = givenWidth;
        height = givenHeight;
    }


    @FXML 
    public void initialize() { //doesn't run this
        SetGrid.build(gridpane, width, height);
    }
```

This is my first time writing in javafx so I may have made simple mistakes, sorry.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't run? Have you tried  a `System.out.println(...)` as the first statement of `initialize`?

Comment: Yes, and I can see when I open it that the columns are not added (also my print statements in the build method of setGrid are not triggered

Comment: If you keep sticking to *static access* you will get into some more trouble soon. Start using *objects*!

Answer (score 5):

You are calling the *static* `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method. Since it's a static method, it doesn't actually reference the `FXMLLoader` instance you created, and so it doesn't reference the controller you set.

Call the instance method `load()` with no parameters instead:

```
final Parent root = loader.load();
```

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            int width = 7;
            int height = 7;         
            final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new GUIController(width, height));

            final Parent root = loader.load();

            final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setTitle("GUI");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this it tells me that the method load() is undefined

Comment: @Tyler It clearly is defined: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-- Can you update your question with an attempt to use the provided code if you are really getting that error?

Comment: @Tyler it is undefined on *class level*, but James_D told you to use the *instance method*. Maybe you better do a step back and learn about classes and objects: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/